# Avoiding collection view "stretched" cells

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm setting up a collection view and customizing its cell's width, inset, and inter-item spacing.  With the current size that means there would be two columns in portrait and three in landscape. I let flow layout do the rotation adjustments & calculations, but the result is a stretched middle column.  I think what is happening is flow layout is doing the math for the cell padding/spacing and not getting clean whole numbers.  Then it adjusts the size of the actual cell by half a point.  The result is an aliased & blurry looking cell.

I'm had this issue multiple times and each time - I manually calculate the values for each orientation to come out as a clean whole number.  While this works, it doesn't seem very efficient.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this, and if FlowLayout has the ability to say, give that half point to a margin or the empty space between the cells?

Comment: Are you using collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath: to return the size that you want for your cells?

Comment: of course =) that or setting them in the nib

Comment: Which are you doing? Setting them in the nib, with the delegate method or both?

Comment: I've been doing one or the other - but prefer setting them in the nib.  However, I've had a few situations where I've wanted to change the size on a rotation so I will use the delegate method

Comment: Still trying to get a solid answer on this one,  I see this issue happen pretty frequently

Comment: I have a test project that has 2 column in portrait and 3 in landscape, and I haven't been able to duplicate your problem, despite changing the insets and cell size to various numbers in IB.